# Show imageview after click wait a moment then hide again [Android]

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview, show-hide

I'm trying to show some imageviews after the user has clicked on a button then wait for some time for the user to see which was the correct button to click then hide it again. Something like this:

User clicks on button giving his answer

-> Score is updated and correct answer is shown to user by setting the visibility of the imageview to visible

-> wait a moment for the user to be able to see which was the correct answer

-> hide the imageview again and load a new question.

So far I have this:

```
private void gameLoop(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                if (time > 0) {
                    sleepmillis(1000);
                    time--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textViewTime.setText(time + " sec.");
                        }
                    });
                } else
                    finishGame();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void sleepmillis(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int givenAnswer = -1;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonFirst:
        case R.id.imageViewFirst:
            givenAnswer = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.buttonSecond:
        case R.id.imageViewSecond:
            givenAnswer = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.buttonThird:
        case R.id.imageViewThird:
            givenAnswer = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.buttonFourth:
        case R.id.imageViewFourth:
            givenAnswer = 3;
            break;
    }
    processAnswer(givenAnswer);
}

private void processAnswer(int givenAnswer){
    if (givenAnswer == answers[4]){
        score += 5000;
        correctAnswersInARow++;
        if (correctAnswersInARow == 3)
            score += 15000;
        if (correctAnswersInARow == 6){
            score += 30000;
            correctAnswersInARow = 0;
        }
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textViewScore.setText("Score: " + score);
        }
    });
    showCorrectAnswer();
    answers = gameData.getAnswers();
    updateAnswers();
}

private void showCorrectAnswer(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (answers[4]){
                case 0:
                    ivCorrectFirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ivCorrectSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ivCorrectThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ivCorrectFourth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    sleepmillis(400);
    hideCorrectAnswers();
}

private void hideCorrectAnswers(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ivCorrectFirst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivCorrectSecond.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivCorrectThird.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ivCorrectFourth.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

So the important part is in the showCorrectAnswer method, where I try to do what I explained here. Although the app waits 400 ms before loading a new question it doesn't show the correct answer.

Comment: Having a sleep in the main UI thread is not recommended. Use a handler-looper combo, if you really must do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      }
    }, ms);
```

ms is time duration in milliseconds.